# twitter bootstrap theme hovering issue - ul li menu item overlayed by slider in home page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

i've modified a [twitter bootstrap theme](http://wbpreview.com/previews/WB06065DN/index.html): I've added some li items to menu hidden ul, here is the [customized page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26311951/home.html).
I have a problem with the menu: on hover event on 'portfolio' item, the ul and the li element contained in it are showed, but they are covered by the slider elements (images and text). I've made an attempt adding white background to li elements of ul, but it doesn't solve the problem. is there any css or other fix to add that can solve the issue?

thanks,
LuKe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `z-index` to the `ul` thats larger than the underlaying items.

Comment: tried, same result. I have to add a position to element, and which?

Comment: It seems like when the carousel moves, the z-index get changed. Maybe a JS workaround. I wouldn't know a better solution.

Comment: maybe i've solved: i've added z-index: 2 to slider element (as you have said in the edit). thanks